# Basic PHP Hit Counter

Tags: php

I can not get this simple PHP hit counter to work.

I have modified the permissions with `chmod` on the `hits.txt` file to `777`.

I tried adding the following code into my index.html, I also tried using it as a separate php file and calling on it with `include`.

```
<?php

$open  = fopen(“hits.txt”, “r+”);
$value = fgets($open);
$close = fclose($open);

$value++;

$open = fopen(“hits.txt”, “w+”);
fwrite($open, $value); // variable is not restated, bug fixed.
$close = fclose($open);

?>
```

and then where I want the results to be displayed, I have:

```
<?php echo $value; ?>
```

Comment: chrome has nothing to do with server side scripts, except in the case that your script checks for user-agent and acts on that info. please post the php code you are currently using so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: What has changed? Who knows? You have posted no code. Anything could be happening here.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code I'm using. But I'm still curious as to why 98% of the hit counter sites I viewed in chrome did not function. The only ones that did were flash based. Weird.

Comment: The string quotes in the code make it invalid.  Switch to single or double quotes and this code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a basic hit counter using a file as the saving point

Script called `myscript.php`

```
<?php
$count = file_get_contents("/path/to/myscript_php_counter_file.txt");
$count++;
file_put_contents("/path/to/myscript_php_counter_file.txt",$count);

//rest of script here.
```

Comment: On a popular website, this can mess things up. I'd use SQL.

Comment: I have found variants of this recipe.  The problem is that if you get a request that reads exactly as the file is being prepared to be written, you'll find that the contents of the file is truncated and the count reads as empty. Hence the counter is reset. Writing to a temporary file, followed by a rename seems to mitigate against this, without applying locking mechanisms.